Wave Equation general solution on 1D
I'm pretty sure the answer is simple but I need some guidance. I'm reading about the wave equation. And when we have it in the following form.
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u(x, t)}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 u(x, t)}{\partial x^2} 
$$
I don't really know how we pass to the solution.
$$
u(x,t)= F(x-t)+G(x+t)
$$
I have read various sources I will point out only wikipedia's general solution, brilliant's solution and libretext's chapter.
In the wikipedia article is more straight forward doing a change of variables
\begin{aligned}
\xi &=x-ct,\\\\ 
\eta &=x+ct
\end{aligned}
Which gives
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta }(x,t)=0
$$
This gives
$$
u(x,t)=F(\xi )+G(\eta )
$$
This last step I don't understand (I mean, it's so basic that every one decides to skip it). I'm sure that is because I'm rusty and unknowledgeable on the basics of differential equations. How do you pass from $\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta }(x,t)=0$ to  $u(x,t)=F(\xi )+G(\eta )$? Any guidance or reference is well appreciated.
By the way, I'm studying this just for fun and for pleasure's sake.

Start with a simpler question: if ${\partial w(\xi,\eta)\over\partial\xi}=0$, then what is $w(\xi,\eta)$?

Here's a general approach which I seem to recall was often the go-to solution to this type of question.
You start of with a differential equation. Then you impose a boundary condition, eg the value and first derivative at time $t=0$. The critical requirement is that these be enough to uniquely determine the solution.
Next, by whatever means, we find a family of solutions. In your case, that simply amounts to proving that expressions on the form $u(x,t)=F(x-t)+G(x+t)$ solves the differential equation. Note that at this point, we do not show that all solutions can be split up like this, only that expressions on this form are solutions.
What then remains is to show that the family of solutions is big enough that it can match the boundary condition. In this case, that could be showing that, for example, given $u(x,0)$ and $\partial u/\partial t(x,0)$, you can find appropriate functions $F$ and $G$.
That gives one solution, and combined with the first result that there is a unique solution, you know that the one you found was the one.
Note that this approach applies to linear differential equations: ie, if $u(x,t)$ and $v(x,t)$ are both solutions, then any linear combination, $a\cdot u(x,t)+b\cdot v(x,t)$ for constants $a$ and $b$, is also a solution.

Two other useful tricks come into play in finding that $u(x,t)$ has solutions on the form $F(x-t)+G(x+t)$.
We can rewrite the differential equation on the form
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)
u(x,t).
$$
In particular, any $u(x,t)$ for which
$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)
u(x,t) = 0$ will be a solution.
I'm sure there are many ways to show that this solution can be written on the form $u(x,t)=F(x-t)$, but one general approach is to look for paths $x=f(t)$ so that $u(f(t),t)$ must be constant along the path: ie $\frac{d}{dt}u(f(t),t)=f'(t)\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$, which happens for $f'(t)=1$ making $f(t)=x_0+t$ and thus $u(x_0+t,t)=u(x_0,0)$.
Again, not that the focus is on producing a solution, not to prove that these are all solutions.
The same argument applies for $
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)
u(x,t)$
